# SPARQL Query to get property that involve one or more individuals

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, endpoint

How do I run a generic sparql query on yago's endpoint to get "concrete" results? For example, I would like to get results like this:

```
"<ELSA_Einstein> <isMarriedTo> <Albert_Einstein>"
"<Albert_Einstein> <hasAccademicAdvisor> <Alfred_Kleiner>"
 etc ..
```

leave the link on which to explore on Yago ontology [YAGO BROWSER](https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/webyagospotlx/Browser). As you can see, these are sentences with a sense, I tried to run this query on this sparql endpoint for ago [SPARQL ENDPOINT FOR YAGO](https://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql)

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?p ?y
WHERE {
?x ?p ?y.
VALUE ?p {rdf: type}                        
} LIMIT 20
```

but the results are not like the ones I posted above here, [Results](https://ibb.co/dHN7gR) (valid triple example   ), how can I bind the predicate so as to get these types of results involving two individuals or at most one 'object must be a string, integer, etc. (literal)?

Comment: The data is there, but there are a lots of schema triples. You have to add a filter on the predicate to avoid seeing those: `SELECT * {
?s ?p ?v. 
?p a rdf:Property .
filter( ?p not in (rdf:type, rdfs:subPropertyOf, rdfs:label, rdfs:comment)) 
} limit 1000`

Comment: @AKSW thank you, but the results I get have the same property (http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/hasThreeLetterLanguageCode) I tried to use ORDER BY RAND () but the situation does not change. [Query result](https://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT+*+%7B+%0D%0A%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fv.+%0D%0A%3Fp+a+rdf%3AProperty.+%0D%0Afilter%28+%3Fp+not+in+%28rdf%3Atype%2C+rdfs%3AsubPropertyOf%2C+rdfs%3Alabel%2C+rdfs%3Acomment%29%29+%0D%0A%7D+limit+1000&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Comment: And the problem is? IT depends on the internal sorting of the triple store which part of the total matching results will be returned. Your query returns almost the whole knowledge base, thus, it's more or less random. It's not clear which results you expect to get? I mean the query is doing what it does correctly. If you want to get results for particular properties, you have to rewrite the query accordingly. Otherwise, you should refine your question and make the problem statement more clear.

Comment: @AKSW I would be interested in different properties but would have a sense (ie, properties that involve an individual or two). I would also like to understand how to export YAGO's ontology and instances to query with Jena Fuseki. (there is only one file that weighs 19gb) how can I query this even on a limited number of instances but locally or with FUSEKI? [YagoDownloadPage](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/)

Comment: What's wrong with loading this file into Jena Fuskeki?

Comment: @AKSW maybe I did not explain well, I wanted to know how to upload yago ontology and instances to FUSEKI so it takes less time to get results. The problem is that I would avoid downloading the 19gb file. Can you download other files on yago's page to query, avoiding that file too large?